# How do i keep one control normal while Blurring the rest of the form in WPF

Tags: wpf, effects

In the code below, I can Blur out all the controls. But I want to prevent one of the buttons from the effect.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Margin="5"/>
    <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button4" Content="Button 4" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button x:Name="button5" Content="Button 5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="button5_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="button6" Content="Button 6" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button7" Content="Button 7" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button8" Content="Button 8" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
    <Button x:Name="button9" Content="Button 9" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>

</Grid>
```

The code behind that does the Blurring:

```
    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BlurEffect blurEffect = new BlurEffect();
        blurEffect.Radius = 3;
        MainGrid.Effect = blurEffect;
    }
```

I've tried adding the code below to reverse the process for just the button I want to keep normal, but it didn't work.

```
    BlurEffect blurEffect = new BlurEffect();
    blurEffect.Radius = 0;
    button5.Effect = blurEffect;
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without blurring all the controls on the form individually?

Thanks

PS. This is just a simplified example for better clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you should be using MVVM instead button click handlers. And you are applying the blur on the entire control, where as you should be doing it on parts of the control. But let's see.

First you should define a style for the blur like so.

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BlurredButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <BlurEffect Radius="3"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

And then in your button click handler you should loop through the buttons of the grid and have some logic to check what buttons should be re-styled. Here I'm not styling the sender. And we apply the new style to all of the buttons.

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var child in this.MainGrid.Children.OfType<Button>())
    {
        if (!object.Equals(sender, child))
        {
            child.Style = this.MainGrid.Resources["BlurredButton"] as Style;
        }
    }
}
```

Or second option would be just have 2 grids on top of each other like so

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button 1" Margin="5"/>
        <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button 2" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button 3" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="button4" Content="Button 4" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <Button x:Name="button6" Content="Button 6" Margin="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="button7" Content="Button 7" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="button8" Content="Button 8" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
        <Button x:Name="button9" Content="Button 9" Margin="5" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button x:Name="button5" Content="Button 5" Margin="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="button5_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Im going to go with the 2 grids method since my "real" program is a bit more complicated than my sample. It never even occurred to me to use 2 grids. And yes I probably should be using MVVM. If only I can find a good tutorial for this old WinForms guys.